# How can I include all eventualities?

Tags: ruby

This code takes in a 3array (position) and tests to see whether it sits in some region of the model or not. The problem is in the PbSheild method, I can't work out why though. This code will work as is (well it will not work as is, that's the point).

```
class Geometry                    

$polyCylRad = 2.5                       
$polyCylFr = 15                         
$polyCylB = -2.0                          
$borPolyBoxL = 9.0 / 2
$pbCylRad = 3.0 
$pbBoxL = 10.0 / 2
$cdBoxL = 9.5 / 2
$xSquared = Float
$ySquared = Float
$zSquared = Float
$modX = Float
$modY = Float
$modZ =Float
$position = Array.new


def checkMaterial(params)

  $position = params
  $xSquared = $position[0] ** 2
  $ySquared = $position[1] ** 2
  $zSquared = $position[2] ** 2
  $modX = Math.sqrt($xSquared)
  $modY = Math.sqrt($ySquared)
  $modZ = Math.sqrt($zSquared)

  puts "polyCyl: " + self.polyCylinder.to_s
  puts "borpoly: " + self.borPolyBox.to_s
  puts "Cd: " + self.CdShield.to_s
  puts "Pb Cylinder: " + self.PbCylinder.to_s
  puts "Pb: " + self.PbShield.to_s
  puts "FreeSpace: " + self.FreeSpace.to_s

  material
end

def polyCylinder
  Math.sqrt($ySquared + $zSquared) <= $polyCylRad && $position[0] >= $polyCylB && $position[0] <= $polyCylFr
end

def borPolyBox
  !polyCylinder && ($modX <= $borPolyBoxL || $modY <= $borPolyBoxL || $modZ <= borPolyBoxL) && !($modX > $borPolyBoxL || $modY > $borPolyBoxL || $modZ > borPolyBoxL)
end

def CdShield
  !polyCylinder && !borPolyBox && ($modX <= $cdBoxL || $modY <= $cdBoxL || $modZ <= $cdBoxL) &&  !($modX > $cdBoxL || $modY > $cdBoxL || $modZ > $cdBoxL)
end

def PbCylinder
  !polyCylinder && $position[0] >= $cdBoxL && $position[0]  <= $polyCylFr && Math.sqrt($ySquared + zSquared) <= $pbCylRad
end 

def PbShield
  !polyCylinder && !borPolyBox && !CdShield && !PbCylinder && ($modX <= $pbBoxL || $modY <= $pbBoxL || $modZ <= $pbBoxL) && !($modX > $pbBoxL || $modY > $pbBoxL || $modZ > $pbBoxL)                                                  
end

def FreeSpace
  !polyCylinder && !borPolyBox && !CdShield && !PbShield && !PbCylinder
end

def material
  [
  [:polyCylinder, 'poly'],
  [:borPolyBox, 'borPoly'],
  [:CdShield, 'Cd'],
  [:PbCylinder, 'Pb'],
  [:PbShield, 'Pb'],
  [:FreeSpace, 'air']
  ].each do |method, name|
  return name if send(method)
              end
  false
end

end

$bob = Geometry.new
posVect = Array.new
posVect << 0 << 0 << 0
$bob.checkMaterial(posVect)

while posVect[0]  < 25 do

$bob.checkMaterial(posVect)
puts "Xpos: " + posVect[0].to_s
puts "Ypos: " + posVect[1].to_s
puts "Zpos: " + posVect[2].to_s
puts "polyCyl: " + $bob.polyCylinder.to_s
puts "borpoly: " + $bob.borPolyBox.to_s
puts "Cd: " + $bob.CdShield.to_s
puts "Pb: " + $bob.PbShield.to_s
puts "FreeSpace: " + $bob.FreeSpace.to_s
puts ""

posVect[0] += 1

end
```

If you think this looks suspiciously like it is related to my c++ code you are correct, am writing two structurally different monte carlo's in Ruby and c++ (learning Ruby and the deepening c++ knowledge at the same time).

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me right away is that you are using a lot of globals where you don't need to. I don't know if that is causing you any issues, but it is definitely not good style. If you want a variable that is accessible only within the class (which seems to be what you want) use an instance variable: @var rather than $var. There's no particular reason to make $bob anything but local here.

Comment: The reason for $bob is that I have used it in a definition outside of the class but the main reason they are globals is for testing, thanks for the instance advice though. :)

Comment: For testing: are you using the Unit Testing Module? This is an absolute life saver. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit/Assertions.html

Comment: nice one, and thanks. Am attempting to work out how to do the same as #include in Ruby.... *embarrassed (I was just going to write a load of classes and save them in one file when each module is done... I am HACKING Ruby (I hope that this term is usually used in a way which describes botching things together, because thats what I am doing at the mo))

Comment: You've probably figured this out, but 'require' is similar to #include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite this entirely. You have a couple of problems that you want to solve. First, you want to define a region and see if a point is within that region. That should probably be one module with a method for defining regions and a method for placing a point within a defined region. You could, if you wished, define the regions in the module itself, or define them on the fly, whichever. That would give you the ability to pass a region name or definition and a point to a single method and get back whether the point is within that region. That would be much easier to test.

Second, you want to determine the material value: true or false, for every material. You might consider using a case statement for this. You write a method that returns values for your region test (like :poly, :box, whatever) and then use that as the test for your case statement:

```
   case whatever(point)
   when (:foo)
     set some values
   when (:bar)
     set some other values
   end
```

If you set the default for every material value to false (a good plan) then you'll only have to update the trues, and it should be easy, based on the return value of your region check method, to decide what values need to be true or can be true.

Breaking the code apart this way--or some other way--will make it much easier to test.

Comment: I see what you are getting at. Less calculations and more modular. However this does not solve my logic problem. The code does not acknowledge when the particle goes out of bounds (into 'air') will rewrite this in the way you suggested and repost if the problem persists. Cheers